# Linux/Centos 7, Machine still runs older cron even after delete

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cron, centos

I have a cron job on Amazon EC2 centos 7 machine.

I have a cron job that 
1. Open other EC2 machine (at 7 morning)
2. Close other EC2 machine (at 9 morning)

I changed it's closing to 10 morning (instead of 9).
**But still machines closes at 9.** and also closes at 10 .

I tried the following:

1. Delete the whole cron job using

> sudo crontab -r

.

Also, checked:

> for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; sudo crontab -u
>   $user -l; done

Which shows cron job is set only for Root user with the correct settings. (close at 10)

I reset Centos machine.
But still same result..

Note: The New cron job closes machine at 10. So machine will close at 9 and 10 which means the older cron job still exist somewhere.

Help Please... Where is the older cron settings are hidden and how to delete them?!

Updated Cron job:

> 58 6 * * * /usr/bin/aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids xyxyxyxyx
>   --region eu-west-1
>
> 55 9 * * * /usr/bin/aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids xyxyxyxyx--
>   --region eu-west-1

(It closes at 8:57 [older cron] and 9:55)

Comment: Check /etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d/* /etc/cron.*/* too just in case

Comment: /etc/cron.d/* contains a file called 0hourly that contains: 
# Run the hourly jobs
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly

Comment: That's normal, check references to your commands

Comment: What do you mean references to my commands ?

Comment: The commands you added in crontab -e ti do your stuff

Comment: I added current cron job to question

Comment: Ok let's make it easier. Run `grep aws /etc/* -rl` and post results

Comment: /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.bin
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.pre
/etc/selinux/targeted/policy/policy.30
/etc/selinux/targeted/active/file_contexts
/etc/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern
/etc/services
/etc/udev/hwdb.bin

Comment: OK, nothing related to cron. Anything relevant in /var/log/cron?

Comment: Strangely doing "sudo cat corn" (to see log) i only see the new  cron job events rising (open at 8 and close at 10), but not the older closing time (close at 9) . It is not in the cron log!  What should i look for inside: /var/log/cron?

Comment: i see, ok, will do so. thanks